# Can you remove arrows on Tkinter Scrollbar widget in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Is it possible for the arrows on the scrollbar widget on Tkinter to be removed and have only the rectangular slider. The scrollbar is currently attached to a list box and does not require the arrows.

If it is not available, is there a way to manually create a scrollbar using Tkinter?

Note: Currently using Python 2.7 
Thanks.

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-autoscrollbar.htm

Comment: @Nae I think the OP only wants to remove the up and down arrows, not to auto-hide the scrollbar.

Comment: Providing a sample code using [mcve] would help increase the question quality IMO.

Comment: @Nae I fully agree, a MCVE always helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ttk.Style` to create a custom scrollbar layout without arrows:

```
style.layout('arrowless.Vertical.TScrollbar', 
             [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough',
               {'children': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', 
                              {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
                'sticky': 'ns'})])
```

And here is the original `Vertical.TScrollbar` layout in the default ttk theme in Linux:

```
[('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough',
  {'children': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''}),
    ('Vertical.Scrollbar.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': ''}),
    ('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
   'sticky': 'ns'})]
```

where you can see the up and down arrows. Here is an example with a listbox:

```
import ttk
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
for i in range(20):
    listbox.insert('end', 'item %i' %i)

style = ttk.Style(root)
# create new scrollbar layout
style.layout('arrowless.Vertical.TScrollbar', 
         [('Vertical.Scrollbar.trough',
           {'children': [('Vertical.Scrollbar.thumb', 
                          {'expand': '1', 'sticky': 'nswe'})],
            'sticky': 'ns'})])
# create scrollbar without arrows           
scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=listbox.yview, 
                       style='arrowless.Vertical.TScrollbar')
listbox.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

listbox.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
root.mainloop()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was unaware of  ttk.Style and with some additional reading I was able to configure it exactly to my liking!